# How to set different Profile Curve resolution for each instanced curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to have a different resolution for each profile curve based on curve index. However, all of the curves end up having the same profile curve resolution.

[image]

[image]

Edit (with deformation):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want this:

[image]

[image]

.......

Comment: Inefficient as hell, but technically it solves the question! I guess there is really no other way.. Would this be a good feature to ask for on Right Click Select?

Comment: @VSB the feature to ask for is loops. There are no real loops in geometry nodes. It is possible, however, to reproduce the curve beveling in geometry nodes and therefore create an efficient alternative. Problem is, the node tree would be so big it would be a poor fit for BSE.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of instantiating the base curve along a line, and extruding a profile along it, you would have to reverse that in this case:

First instantiate the profile curves, subdivide them as you wish, and extrude them all together along your base curve.

This could look something like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Can you make that work with instanced curves instead of instanced profiles? Or with instanced curves and instanced profiles?

Comment: @VSB Unfortunately, I do not understand this question. The curves used here are "profiles" (*Profile Curve*) for `Curve to Mesh`. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The file I provided is a very simplified version. Actual application instances curve lines and not the Profile Curve, so above needs to also instance the Curve Line. There is a deformation applied to the curve line creating a variation. I have uploaded a more complex example.

Comment: @VSB Ah, now I understand what you mean. I'm afraid this won't work, unfortunately. `Curve to Mesh` extrudes along one or more base curves, which can also be different, but it always uses all passed profile curves at once for each extrusion. Unfortunately, with this node you can't selectively decide on which base curve to extrude which profile, so you'd have to think of another solution. Sorry, this is the way this node works.